# How can I delete the results from a 'where' query in Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've got Azure running a Node server with the Azure-mobile-apps package, `"azure-mobile-apps": "^3.0.1"`. I can use `req.azureMobile` to get results from any given table within an EasyAPI file:

```
module.exports = {
    get: asyncMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
        const deviceTable = req.azureMobile.tables('Devices');

        var results = await deviceTable.where(function(date) {
            return this.last_active < date
        }, new Date(2018,5,5)).read();

        res.status(201).send(results);
    })
};
```

But what if I wanted to *delete* the results of the `where` clause?

```
module.exports = {
    delete: asyncMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
        const deviceTable = req.azureMobile.tables('Devices');

        await deviceTable.where(function(date) {
            return this.last_active < date
        }, new Date(2018,5,5)).delete();

        res.status(201).send();
    })
};
```

I've tried the above, foolishly, but it didn't work. I find the documentation for azure-mobile-apps difficult to find and difficult to understand. I found this page [right here](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_data.html#~delete), but this doesn't tell me anything I can use.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I've found the answer, not entirely sure. I tried this and it seemed to soft-delete exactly the records I was trying to:

```
module.exports = {
    delete: asyncMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
        const deviceTable = req.azureMobile.tables('Devices');

        await deviceTable.delete(deviceTable.where(function(date) {
            return this.last_active < date
        }, new Date(2018,5,5)));

        res.status(201).send();
    })
};
```

The annoying thing is that this seems to *error* when there are 0 records to delete, which seems like unexpected behaviour to me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I followed your code and tested the following code on my side:

```html
req.azureMobile.tables('TodoItem')
   .delete(req.azureMobile.tables('TodoItem')
   .where(function(id){return this.id ==id;},req.query.id))
   .then(results=>{
       //res.json(results);
        res.status(201).send(results);
   })
   .catch(next);
```

Before I tested the above code, I enabled [diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) for my web app and go to "MONITORING > Log stream" of my web app on Azure Portal to see the real time logging.

After sent the delete request, I could see a log look likes this:

> 2018-07-03T08:59:48.551Z - �[35msilly�[39m: Executing SQL statement **SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TodoItem] WHERE ([id] = @p1);DELETE FROM [dbo].[TodoItem] WHERE ([id] = @p1);SELECT @@rowcount AS recordsAffected**; with parameters [{"name":"p1","pos":1,"value":"123"}]

For a simple way, I just go to "MOBILE > Easy tables" of my app service and found that my previous deleted record has been completely deleted. Also, I tried to retrieve the previous record via the browser by adding a additional query parameter `__includeDeleted` as follows:

```
https://{your-mobile-app}.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoitem/{record-id}?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0&__includeDeleted=true
```

**Note:** If the record does not exist, then I would receive the 404 status code and the following text message:

```
{
    "error": "The item does not exist"
}
```

From my testing, the above process could also be implemented  as follows:

```html
 req.azureMobile.tables('TodoItem')
    .delete({id:req.query.id})
    .then(results=>{
       //res.json(results);
        res.status(201).send(results);
   });
```

Per my testing, the above delete operations would completely delete the record instead of setting the `deleted` field to true, and if the record does not exit, then you would receive the 404 error.

Moreover, I checked that we could use [execute(statement)](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_data_execute.html#~execute) to execute custom SQL statement with no exception even if the record does not exist. Here is the code snippet, you could refer to it:

```html
var query = {
    sql: 'UPDATE TodoItem SET DELETED=1 where id=@id',
    parameters: [
        {name:'id',value:req.query.id}
    ]
};

req.azureMobile.data.execute(query).then(function (results) {
    res.json(results);
});
```

Comment: In the part after you said, `From my testing, the above process could also be implemented as follows:`, that code is only applicable when I have an ID, not in my use case which is a more complex query (I deliberately included my example as a date comparison, because that's my need). And for some reason, when I do use `var result = await delete(where())`, the promise from delete doesn't actually return anything.